# Looking for recommendations on a good ** beginners ** bash tutorial

Tags: bash, command-line

I am an ETL developer by profession that just started reading *The Pragmatic Programmer* by Dave Thomas & Andrew Hunt. I have been meaning to learn more about bash & command line in Ubuntu for a while but reading this book made me realize how essential it is for me to start learning it. Therefore, I would love to get some recommendation from the StackOverflow community on a good beginner tutorial/reference to bash. I am looking for something that gives me a lot of example commands to play with and some exercises/challenges.

Thank you all very much!

Ashish

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) is a classic and comprehensive Bash reference/tutorial.

Comment: +1 Truly comprehensive from novice to expert. Includes caveats and plenty of cut-in-paste examples.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the title to reflect that I am looking for a beginner's tutorial but based on your comment, I should not be scared as a novice. I will give it a whirl. Thanks!

Comment: Not so sure about this one, I've read (on SO among others), that it was outdated, had errors and was not a reference concerning good bash coding practices (quite the opposite actually).

Answer (score 2):

Two ressources i would recommend:

1. The book "Learning the bash Shell" from Cameron Newham and Bill Rosenblatt.
2. The [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).
3. The [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) (although it might be a bit hard)

Answer (score 2):

Kernighan and Pike's [The Unix Programming Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013937681X) will show you how experts use the Unix command line. They write several small tools throughout the book, many of which are shell scripts. It doesn't focus on bash (bash didn't exist at the time!), but rather the standard bourne shell (sh). You can learn bash's non-portable extensions after you're comfortable with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

[This Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) was quite clear, progressive and comprehensive for me. It has the advantage to teach you about good practices as well, especially by showing what is good practice and what is not.
On top of this, you can always ask questions and get help on the IRC channel, which is, in my opinion a great plus when learning.