# directories and file arrangement in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a script that will put files with different extensions into their specified  directories .

In the directory are files of various types, i want to arrange the files on individual directories under their type. There are three distinct types of files:

1. Text documents - files with extensions. Doc,. Txt,. Pdf, ...
2. multimedia files - with the extensions. Mpg,. Avi,. Mp3 ...
3. graphics files - with the extensions. Jpg,. Gif,. Png ...
4. All other files

Files types 1-3 to move into individual directories and files of other types have to move in directories with names corresponding to the extension (you can bring them to uppercase - BAK, CPP ,...).

i want the script to run with the following parameters:

1. -m path - if specified, the multimedia files will be moved to the directory PATH
2. -d PATH - specifies the path where you have to move your documents
3. -l indicates that when the file names should lead to lower case
4. -x indicates that they move to lower case file extension

any ideas?? I am a newbie and I'm trying to learn bash scripting so I thought of this question

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a good program to get your feet wet and get familiar with bash scripting.

Comment: Find some tutorials on bash scripting which should get you to the point of tackling this. Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600139/looking-for-recommendations-on-a-good-beginners-bash-tutorial to start with.

Answer (score 3):

This should be easy. Learn how `mv` works, how to manipulate string variables in bash (aka parameter expansion), and how to handle arguments. You can use `tr` to handle lower- and upper-casing.

Comment: he? should learn about getopt/getopts (and the crucial differences between the two) as well as looping structures and case statements ;-) Good luck to all.